# Javascript combining methodology

Tags: php, javascript, caching, minify

What is the appropriate methodology for combining js files for production?

For example, I have some files (lets call them Category A files) that are used on all pages in the app, and some files (called Category B files) that are only used on 3 or 4 pages.

Given that I am minifying and caching (and combining where appropriate) all js files, should I:

1. Combine the Category B files with the Category A files into a single cached file; or
2. Always serve the Category A files, and only serve the Category B on those pages that need them?

I suspect that option 1 is the preferred route, but I just wanted to double check.

Comment: You might benefit from reviewing [Yahoo's Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html), although in practice you may not benefit all that much from slavishly following *every* rule (keep in mind return-on-investment, or ROI). Premature optimization can be less useful than working with an approach and adjusting if and when it proves problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conbining them into one and minifing it, it's probably the way to go.
Less files on the page request.